# Error inflating XML class - Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)

Tags: android, android-resources, inflate-exception

Why when I run my project I get this error? I've been searching for this issue but I didn't find any solution for it

```
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException:             
 Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

It´s a simple sign up activity.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl8iR.png)

**Here is the code:**

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<include layout="@layout/layout_topbar_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/signup_toolbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/signup_toolbar">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/form_email_short"
        android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_white_square"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_edit_text"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/form_password_short"
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_white_square"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_edit_text"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Sign Up!"
        android:id="@+id/btn_create"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/button_accent_square"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**The toolbar XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**The edittext drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="@color/white"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/greyXLight"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

I'm testing it in an emulator with API 22 and min API 16

Please let me know if you need more info.
Thanks.

Comment: Please read your logcat again... Look at the `ResourceNotFoundException`

Comment: I just post the xml of the drawable file, because I don't see the issue. I'm new in android development.

Comment: What folder does your drawable exist in? res/??

Comment: yes, in res/drawable-v24

Comment: Okay. So, you're running an emulator with API 22 trying to load a Drawable only available from 24+ because why?

Comment: I only can say thanks. I really don't know why this is the only xml file in that folder.

Comment: Probably because that's the api level you set when you created the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drawable isn't too complicated that it needs to be in a specific API level.

Move it to  `res/drawable` (create this if it doesn't exist).

Or at least make a `v16` drawable folder so it corresponds to the minimum API level you've set

Comment: Thanks! It's fixed